# Is the line of code of a static type declaration read only once?

Tags: c

So if I declare a static type in a function, every time that the function is called again, the content of the type wont be declared again. So my question is, imagine the following code:

```
1 int fun(int n){
2 static int a = 4;
3 return (a+=n);
4
5 }
```

So, the first time fun() is called it will read it from line 1, but from n time n>=2 it is called, it will be read from line 3 ignoring line 2 right?

So could fun() be equivalent to fun2()? -> (the variable now is global)

```
0  int a = 4;
1 int fun2(int n){
2
3 return(a+=n);
4
5 }
```

Comment: "*So could fun() be equivalent to fun2()?*". What do you find when you run and test the two versions?

Comment: The same result

Comment: C is almost always a translated language, not an interpreted one. The source code is read once, analyzed by the compiler, and translated into machine code. The source code is not read when the function is called; it is read when the source file is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes they're functionally the same.  The main difference between a file scope variable and a `static` local  is where the name is accessible.

Comment: so basically static can be used only inside the function and scope in all functiones right? And the line of the static type is read only once right?

Comment: @Elrisas yes it has full program lifetime and local scope.